# Retrieve files from Dirrectory

Tags: ios, xcode5

My Application creates Png, Pdf, and Jpg files and stores in Documentary with different name formats. How can i retrieve all filetypes at a time. For example If i want to count how many number of pdf files in documentary, where all files exists and i have to count only pdf files. How can i achieve this for particular file types.

```
   NSFileManager *filemanage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *filelist= [filemanage contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];

NSInteger filescount = [filelist count];
NSString *filesnumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", filescount];
NSLog(@"filesnumber:%@", filesnumber);
fileLabel.text = filesnumber;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *filemanage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *filelist= [filemanage contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];

NSInteger filescount = 0;
for (NSString *fileName in filelist) {
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
        filescount++;
    }
}

NSString *filesnumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", filescount];
NSLog(@"filesnumber:%@", filesnumber);
fileLabel.text = filesnumber;
```

You could || the if statement to add .jpg, .png and whatever else you may want.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFileManager *filemanage = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *filelist = [filemanage contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];

NSInteger fileCountPDF = 0;
for (NSString *fileName in filelist) {
    NSString *extension = fileName.pathExtension;

    if ([extension caseInsensitiveCompare:@"pdf"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"PDF file found");
        fileCountPDF++;
    }
}

NSLog(@"PDF files: %d",fileCountPDF);

//...
```